# replaceAll pastes part of unnecessary extra string

Tags: java, replaceall

This is my example java code:

```
String oldContent = "Book 1;Author 1;11|11\n" +
        "Book 2;Author 2;1|1\n" +
        "Book 3;Author 3;1|1\n" +
        "Book 4;Author 4;1|1\n" +
        "Book 5;Author 5;1|1\n";

String old = "Book 1;Author 1;11";
String newS = "Book 1;Author 1;12|12";

String content = oldContent.replace(old,newS);

System.out.println(content);
```

I'm trying to update part of String in oldContent (old) with new part of string (newS). The result should be:

```
Book 1;Author 1;12|12
Book 2;Author 2;1|1
Book 3;Author 3;1|1
Book 4;Author 4;1|1
Book 5;Author 5;1|1
```

but actually is:

```
Book 1;Author 1;12|12|11
Book 2;Author 2;1|1
Book 3;Author 3;1|1
Book 4;Author 4;1|1
Book 5;Author 5;1|1
```

with these extra `|11` . Could someone explain me how it works and why? I have been trying with `replace()`, `replaceAll()` but result is the same.

Comment: You don't replace the complete line, only a part of it (the part without the `|11`). Obviously it won't replace that part then. If you want to replace it too, it should be part of your replace statement `old`. `String old = "Book 1;Author 1;11|11";`. If you rather search for a *"if that part is contained in the line, replace the whole line"*-logic, u need a more sophisticated approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing `Book 1;Author 1;11|11` sequence with `Book 1;Autor 1;12|12` sequence however the first line ends with `1:11|11`. Notice the extra `|11` at the end of a line, it won't be processed and will be appended to `Book 1;Autor 1;12|12`.

To fully replace first line you need:

```
String old = "Book 1;Autor 1;11|11";
String newS = "Book 1;Autor 1;12|12";
String content = oldContent.replace(old, newS);
```

Comment: oh of course you are right. Now I see where I have mistake. Thank you! Stupid mistake...

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention! You have typo in `Author` word:

```
String old = "Book 1;Author 1;11|11";
String newS = "Book 1;Author 1;12|12";
String content = oldContent.replace(old, newS);
```